# Reading from input stream with other bases than 10

Tags: c++, stream, inputstream

I have noticed that `std::oct` and `std::hex` can be used to write to output stream as 8, 16 base.
Is it same way to read from input stream as 8 or 16 base system instead of normal 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::hex` and `std::oct` manipulators with `std::cin`, for instance:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    std::cin >> std::hex >> i;
    std::cout << i;
}
```

When the input is `b`, the output of this program will be:

```
11
```

See a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx%24178) that demonstrates the use of both manipulators. The input is `b`, followed by a new line character, followed by `10`.

Comment: Also look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387386/using-c-hex-and-cin

Comment: Thank you. Why I didn't try it myself? :-? and why everywhere (at least everywhere that I have seen) examples expressed with cout only!!!